# Http request intercept not showing any log info

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to intercept an http request to see what the actual data sent and received is, however nothing shows up in my log.

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun webData() {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL).addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create()).build()
        val service = retrofit.create(GetService::class.java)
        val serviceData = service.getData().body()
        getData.postValue(serviceData)
    }
```

}

Comment: You create the `interceptor`, but then you do not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct but is not complete, try this:

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun webData() {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL).client(client).addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create()).build()
        val service = retrofit.create(GetService::class.java)
        val serviceData = service.getData().body()
        getData.postValue(serviceData)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked great !